# Building a Linq Query from a List<string> using dynamic linq

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I am using dynamic linq to preocess some user requests.  The way it was set up is that I would gather the data into Var data

```
var data = Project.Model.Adhoc.GetData().AsQueryable();
```

This is basically a select * from a view

Then from there I would loop through all of the options that I have to filter that the user selected

```
 foreach (Filters filter in filters.OrderBy(x=>x.strOrderNumber))
            {
```

along with some checks and permutations, I get down to this

```
data = data.Where(filter.strFilter + FormatOperator(filter.strOperator) + "@0", filter.strValue).
                                Select(x => x).ToList().AsQueryable();
```

This is working pretty well, however the datasource is starting to grow, so what I would like to do is something like this:

`data = data.select(get all items that were selected)` and then do my checks and permutations.  This would allow me to only pull what is needed, not the entire datasource.  What is the best way in C# using linq to accomplish this.

Ex.

```
datasource = {Name, Age, Race, Gender, Hair Color, Eye Color, height, weight, etc}

user selected = {Name, Age, Race, Gender}
```

Instead of querying against that whole datasource, I want to limit the datasource to only what is brought in by the user off the bat, and then I can filter based on that as teh datasource

Comment: Just so I understand, you essentially want to send a "select * from myView where x = [something] and y = [something else]" so that the SQL server only returns the limited results, right?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `.ToList()` call in the foreach loop.

`data = data.Where()` will build a query expression with `AND`s. So after the loop you can finally invoke .ToList() to finally hit the database.

**Update**

And the .Select() isn't necessary.

```
data = data.Where(filter.strFilter + FormatOperator(filter.strOperator) + "@0", filter.strValue);
```

**Update2**

Oh, after reading your question again I get that you need to build the query using OR.

This is a little bit more difficult using the standard library. If you don't mind pulling in a extra dependency then it can (probably) be done using [LinqKit](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx)

```
IQueryable<Product> SearchProducts (params string[] keywords)
{
    var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<Product>();

    foreach (string keyword in keywords)
    {
        string temp = keyword;
        predicate = predicate.Or (p => p.Description.Contains (temp));
    }
    return dataContext.Products.Where (predicate);
}
```

Although I am not sure how well that works together with Dynamic Linq.

Otherwise you'll have to handcraft the expression, which might end up looking similar to this:

```
public static class IQueryableExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<T> WhereIn<T, TValue>(
        this IQueryable<T> source,
        Expression<Func<T, TValue>> propertySelector,
        IEnumerable<TValue> values)
    {
        return source.Where(GetWhereInExpression(propertySelector, values));
    }

    private static Expression<Func<T, bool>> GetWhereInExpression<T, TValue>(
        Expression<Func<T, TValue>> propertySelector, IEnumerable<TValue> values)
    {
        if (!values.Any())
            return c => false;

        ParameterExpression p = propertySelector.Parameters.Single();

        // You'll have to adjust this:
        var equals = values.Select(value => (Expression)Expression.Equal(
                propertySelector.Body, Expression.Constant(value, typeof(TValue))));

        var body = equals.Aggregate<Expression>(
                (accumulate, equal) => Expression.Or(accumulate, equal));
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, p);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at **[Dynamic Linq](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx)**

> You can use the DynamicQuery library against any LINQ data provider
>   (including LINQ to SQL, LINQ to Objects, LINQ to XML, LINQ to
>   Entities, LINQ to SharePoint, LINQ to TerraServer, etc).  Instead of
>   using language operators or type-safe lambda extension methods to
>   construct your LINQ queries, the dynamic query library provides you
>   with string based extension methods that you can pass any string
>   expression into.